# SSIS package deployment failure after SQL server default TCP port change + original package execution pending

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

I have a case that SQL server is running remotely and recently the SQL server TCP port is changed from 1433 to 61433. After service reboot, I can connect to the server by (server name, port number) but cannot deploy packages from VS2019 to the server remotely.

I tried to query with operation_id provided but I couldn't find the id specified. Also, when I try to run old SSIS package deployed on SQL server, it will show 'pending execution' and the execution never stops.
Have I missed any steps of SSIS package or SSISDB setting after port change? Thanks for help.

Symptom:

Deploy result failure message
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESDVh.png)

Details
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2WP.png)

Ongoing Pending packages
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WGsB.png)

Port number changed to 61433
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J37xo.png)